# Why would SecKeyEncrypt return paramErr (-50) for input strings longer than 246 bytes?

Tags: ios, public-key-encryption

I am using `SecKeyEncrypt` with a JSON formatted string as input. If pass `SecKeyEncrypt` a plainTextLength of less than 246, it works. If I pass it a length of 246 or more, it fails with return value: `paramErr (-50)`.

It could be a matter of the string itself. An example of what I might send `SecKeyEncrypt` is:

```
{"handle":"music-list","sym_key":"MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBALeaEO7ZrjgOFGLBzBHZtQuzH2GNDYMLWP+fIFNu5Y+59C6HECY+jt0yOXXom2mzp/WYYI/9G+Ig8OD6YiKv2nMCAwEAAQ==","app_id":"xgfdt.LibraryTestApp","api_key":"7e080f74de3625b90dd293fc8be560a5cdfafc08"}
```

The 245th character is '0'.

The ONLY input that is changing between this working and is the plainTextLength. `SecKeyGetBlockSize()` is returning 256 to me, so any input up to 256 characters long should work.

Here is my encrypt method:

```
+ (NSData*)encrypt:(NSString*)data usingPublicKeyWithTag:(NSString*)tag
{

    OSStatus status = noErr;

    size_t cipherBufferSize;
    uint8_t *cipherBuffer;

    // [cipherBufferSize]
    size_t dataSize = 246;//[data lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    const uint8_t* textData = [[data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] bytes];

    SecKeyRef publicKey = [Encryption copyPublicKeyForTag:tag];

    NSAssert(publicKey, @"The public key being referenced by tag must have been stored in the keychain before attempting to encrypt data using it!");

    //  Allocate a buffer

    cipherBufferSize = SecKeyGetBlockSize(publicKey);
    // this value will not get modified, whereas cipherBufferSize may.
    const size_t fullCipherBufferSize = cipherBufferSize;
    cipherBuffer = malloc(cipherBufferSize);

    NSMutableData* accumulatedEncryptedData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:0];

    //  Error handling

    for (int ii = 0; ii*fullCipherBufferSize < dataSize; ii++) {
        const uint8_t* dataToEncrypt = (textData+(ii*fullCipherBufferSize));
        const size_t subsize = (((ii+1)*fullCipherBufferSize) > dataSize) ? fullCipherBufferSize-(((ii+1)*fullCipherBufferSize) - dataSize) : fullCipherBufferSize;

        // Encrypt using the public key.
        status = SecKeyEncrypt(    publicKey,
                               kSecPaddingPKCS1,
                               dataToEncrypt,
                               subsize,
                               cipherBuffer,
                               &cipherBufferSize
                               );

        [accumulatedEncryptedData appendBytes:cipherBuffer length:cipherBufferSize];
    }

    if (publicKey) CFRelease(publicKey);

    free(cipherBuffer);

    return accumulatedEncryptedData;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the documentation:

> *plainTextLen*
>   Length in bytes of the data in the plainText buffer. This must be less than or equal to the value returned by the SecKeyGetBlockSize function. **When PKCS1 padding is performed, the maximum length of data that can be encrypted is 11 bytes less than the value returned by the SecKeyGetBlockSize function (secKeyGetBlockSize() - 11).**

(emphasis mine)

You're using PKCS1 padding. So if the block size is 256, you can only encrypt up to 245 bytes at a time.